# Cannot create UNIX socket in /run

Tags: c, linux

According to FSH UNIX Sockets shall be created in `/run` (or on legacy distros in `/var/run`). I am trying to create a socket in a non-root application in that directory and get error 13. Is `/run` only for services started via systemd/init? If so, where do you put UNIX sockets from user applications?

Comment: You can put local sockets in any valid location. Just provide a full absolute path and it will be located there (if you have the rights). `/tmp` is a common base directory.

Comment: okay thank you, that was the info I was looking for :) i just want to be according to valid standarts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is /run only for services started via systemd/init?

For root, yes.

> where do you put UNIX sockets from user applications?

On modern systems in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` if the variable is set, with fallback to `/run/user/$UID` if not set. For portability, you can use `/tmp`.

Usually `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` will be just set to `/run/user/$uid`.

https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Linux/fhs/run/user/uid/index https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html